# Detaching source from individual in Family Tree Maker 2017?

Tags: sources, family-tree-maker

Is there a way to detach an incorrect source from an individual in Family Tree Maker 2017?

A source was entered for an emigration fact and later a more accurate and complete source was located.  I have entered the second source, but cannot remove the first one from the individual fact.

Answer (score 3):

In the panel on the right side of the screen (on the "Person" page) there is a small menu line with an unlink icon.  Highlight the source and click the icon.

That being said, I would recommend keeping every source, as long as it is a legitimate one.  I even keep sources where the facts are wrong, though I make sure to note the correct ones.  I find this very helpful in the long term.

[image]